# Why does pydantic call a root validator when a field validator has already failed?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a complicated settings class made with `pydantic` (v. 1.10): a `BaseModel`-inherited class whose fields are also `BaseModel`-inherited classes.

I have root validators for both main settings class and its fields.

At first, root validators for fields should be called. After that (and only if the fields' root validators did not fail) the main settings class's root validator should be called.

And after that I have noticed that main settings class root validator is called even in case when the field validator has already failed.

Here's a simple example:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class TableSettings(BaseModel):
    full_name: Optional[str] = None
    short_name: Optional[str] = None

    @root_validator(pre=True, skip_on_failure=False)
    def _check_name(cls, vals_dict):
        print("Checking a field: it will crash...")
        if "full_name" not in vals_dict and "short_name" not in vals_dict:
            raise ValueError("Either full_name or short_name should be set!")


class EtlSettings(BaseModel):
    table_settings: Dict[str, TableSettings]

    extra_options: Dict[str, Any] = {}

    @root_validator(pre=False)
    def _do_not_call_me_if_src_settings_are_invalid(cls, vals_dict):
        print("This validator should never be called in case of the fields have invalid data!!!!")
        print(vals_dict)

        # Here will be crash, that should be avoided because this validator should be callled
        # only if the fields are validated!
        print(vals_dict["table_settings"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_dict = {"table_settings": {"valid_table": {}}}  # It should crash on field's root validator
    
    
    etl_settings = EtlSettings(**raw_dict)
    # It crashes on field's root validator but root main validator is called too. WHY???
```

Here's what it prints:

```
Checking a field: it will crash...
This validator should never be called in case of the fields have invalid data!!!!
{'extra_options': {}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/fs_etl/mega_validation_fuss.py", line 31, in <module>
    etl_settings = EtlSettings(**raw_dict)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 339, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 1102, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/fs_etl/mega_validation_fuss.py", line 26, in _do_not_call_me_if_src_settings_are_invalid
    print(vals_dict["table_settings"])
KeyError: 'table_settings'
```

How can I avoid calling of my main root validator when field's root validator has failed?